# Auto-hiding columns based on cell criteria in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I am new to VBA coding and have so far successfully managed to create a scoping sheet in a workbook which hides/unhides tabs based on workbooks users' responses to yes/no questions.

I need to further refine the workbook so that the yes/no responses provided in the scoping tab lead to the **auto** hiding of columns in other sheets. Using a previous thread on this website I used this code (obviously amended for my own cells refs) on one of the tabs:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$6" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "Cast"
            Columns("f").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Columns("d").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("e").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "LDF"
            Columns("f").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("d").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Columns("e").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "Select ROV Type"
            Columns("f").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Columns("d").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Columns("e").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End Select
```

In B6, I have a formula (=Name) which pulls through from the scoping tab. While the above code works, it only does so where I manually enter the cell to re-pull through data... any hints on:
- linking through to the original scoping tab in my macro, bypassing the cell reference; and 
- automating the column hides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do seems to edit your code like this, where needed:

```
Sheet2.Columns("f").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

Sheet2 is the sheet, where the columns should be hidden.

Comment: This was great, thanks. I just added this line of code to the original scoping tab. Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly interpreted your needs go like follows

In "ThisWorkbook" code pane place the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Sheets("scoping sheet") '<== here you set which sheet you want to monitor
        If .Range("B6") <> .Range("A1") Then '<== check if the "formula" cell changed its previous value, stored in the "echo" cell ("A1")

            Select Case .Range("B6").Value
                Case Is = "Cast"
                    .Columns("f").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    .Columns("d").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    .Columns("e").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Case Is = "LDF"
                    .Columns("f").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    .Columns("d").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    .Columns("e").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                Case Is = "Select ROV Type"
                    .Columns("f").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    .Columns("d").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    .Columns("e").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End Select

            .Range("a1") = .Range("b6") '<== update the "echo" cell value for subsequent checking

        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

As you see, you must choose an "echo" cell in the "scoping" sheet, which will be used to store the previous value of its "B6" cell.

In my code I chose cell "A1" as the "echo" cell in "scoping" sheet, but you can choose whatever address you need provided it's a "free" cell (i.e.: your code and the user won't use it to write in) and change code accordingly (i.e. the `"A1"` address in `If .Range("B6") <> .Range("A1") Then` statement).